# Rails 3 Remote Form Ajax Success

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I'm having some issue figuring out how to handle success on my entries form using rails 3 ujs ajax.

If there are errors, I have a create.js.erb that will `alert(j(@entry.errors.full_messages)`, and this works.  But if there are no errors, the form doesn't redirect (because I'm rendering in a dialog) and I'd like the js to alert("success") and close the dialog. (using fancybox 2).

Can you give me some pointers working with rails 3 ujs and ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach is to identify and handle the error at controller level instead of view.

```
def create
  @entry = something
  if @entry.save
    @notice = "Success message!"
    respond_to :js # render default create.js.erb
  else
    respond_to :js { render 'create_error.js.erb' }
  end
end

// create.js.erb
$("#dialog").close();
alert("<%= @notice %>">;

// create_error.js.erb
alert(j(@entry.errors.full_messages);
```

Comment: A better fancybox close is `$.fancybox.close();`   :)

Comment: @KevinBrown, actually I don't know the method at all :) That is just an example to show different actions on different template.

Comment: @KevinBrown, maybe `alert` is just your example method, you may use more friendly method such as `show()`, `fadeIn()` etc. No matter what they are, in real case they are better to be the callback method of `close()`, to be fired after the dialogue closed.

Comment: Indeed, Billy. Thanks for the prompt answer! Perhaps you can expand to the rails 3 way of responding_to :js, :html, :json with independant params for each?

Comment: hi @BillyChan, i have note about :success and :complete callback which doesn't be triggered for the new elements when using ujs, is this method an alternative to this problem ?

Comment: @medBo, I noticed your problem as well though it's not related to this question. To fix this, you can use jQuery's `ajaxComplete` event instead of UJS's.

Comment: @BillyChan i post my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384720/ajaxsuccess-and-ajaxcomplete-callback-doesnt-work-when-using-ujs-in-rails if you can help me on that please, i confuse things :(